# Laravel: How to use scope with mass assignment

Tags: php, laravel

I have two entities with many to many relationship: `Form` and `Section`. A valid section must to be "active" then I have a scope:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param Builder $query
 * @return Builder
 */
public function scopeActive($query) 
{
    return $query->where('is_active', true);
}
```

And when rendering the form, just pass the active sections to the view:

```
$sections = Section::active()->get();
```

The problem is that when the POST request is sent, I have to perform a mass assignment in relationship with [sync](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) and have not control over the id's passed (actives and not actives):

```
$form->sections()->sync($sectionsId);
```

**There is a way to attach only active sections without manually checking each one?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take sections in **$sectionIds** first and then you have to use **sync()** method.
Try this code,

```
$sectionIds = Section::active()->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])->pluck('id');
$form->sections()->sync($sectionIds);
```

I believe that this will work.

Comment: Would you like to show your  dump  of $sectionsId ?

Comment: it is an array of integers like `[0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 3, 3 => 4]`

Comment: another point is that sync is not a collection method like you suppose in second snippet

Comment: sync all sections of `$sectionsId` array that matches with active sections. Let's say that if in `[1, 2, 3]` the id `3` is not active, the method should only sync intermediate table to `[1, 2]` and ignore the inactive

Comment: do you have model for section?

Comment: and you are sending IDs of that sections in POST..right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167285/discussion-between-chirag-patel-and-alexandre-thebaldi).